# how do I find this file /usr/local/lib/php.ini

Tags: apache-2.2

I have an account with a hosting company and I have FTP access, how do I find this file 
/usr/local/lib/php.ini 
When my root directory after looging in to ftp includes the following folders
-admin_backups
-domains
-imap
-Maildir
-user_backups

Comment: That... doesn't sound like that's where that file would be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, depending on how the hosting company has things set up, you may not have access to that file. You can try to gain access by changing "up" a few directories to "/". Then follow the path down to /usr/local/lib/php.ini.

What specifically are you looking for in php.ini?

Comment: Well okay then. I hope you got what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Many hosting providers won't allow you to directly modify your php.ini. However you should be able to put `ini_set('parameter', 'value');` at the top of your script to change a configuration parameter.